# What's the wrong with udp code in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I hope to receive 300*3 = 900 of messages at "192.168.1.114" in multi thread case, but 876 messages arrived. however, it can all arrived by single thread. and it also can all arrived by sendto '127.0.0.1'. 
Is it because of the reasons for UDP?

```
import socket
import threading
from time import sleep

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
host = '192.168.1.114'
port = 9999

def sendMsg(args):
    msg = 'thread %06d - 1' % args
    s.sendto(msg, (host, port))
    sleep(1)

    msg = 'thread %06d - 2' % args
    s.sendto(msg, (host, port))
    sleep(1)

    msg = 'thread %06d - 3' % args
    s.sendto(msg, (host, port))

threads = []
for i in range(300):
    t = threading.Thread(target=sendMsg, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
for j in threads:
    j.join()

s.close()
```

Comment: UDP is unreliable. There are no guarantees that datagrams will be delivered.

Comment: 300 threads in a single program is a bit too much.

Comment: Your remark that all messages were sent by one thread doesn't seem right. If that were the case, then only that one thread would send 3 messages; you wouldn't arrive at 876. You could send the thread ID in the message, along with your counter, to see what's going on. Also, to account for the lost messages, you'd have to show your server. Is it busy processing stuff while next messages arrive (and since it's UDP, these would get silently discarded)?

Comment: Threads take resources and you may have hit some limit based on the amount of memory or something. Is there anything in the system logs? Try 876/3 threads.